# VMware - more disk space

Tags: partitioning, vmware

I want to expand my disk size, so I did it in the settings of my virtual machine, and not it says 30GB, but when I power on Ubuntu and check in Disks, it still says 20GB, and the 10GB isn't working. How to fix it?

[image: here's a screenshot of it]

Comment: Have you seen [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049955/1222991)? Nothing has changed in the last few years, so the process should work for you 

Comment: This is what I see: 
https://ibb.co/Y34hdx4
https://ibb.co/4RNgF6V
https://ibb.co/ZGVDzr8

Maybe I didn't understand it, but I can't choose more than that 20GB.

Answer (score 0):

I will spare no effort to help you.

Just as your second photo shows, the main/primary partition of your VM's disk is `Partition 1` and partition files type is `FAT`; the extended partition of your VM's disk is `Partition 2`; the logical partition of your VM's disk is `Partition 5` and partition file type is ext4; also, your VM's disk still have `11 GB` free space.

As I know,

Principle-A: Size(vm_disk) == Size(main partition) + Size(extended partition);

Principle-B: Size(extended partition) == All the Size(logical partition);

Principle-C: Size(logical partition) <= Size(extended partition);

So, if you want to expand your VM's Disk size, you should expand logical partition `Partition 5`; but you should firstly enlarge your extended partition `Partition 2` before you start to resize your logical partition `Partition 5`.

Just use sudo `cfdisk` to check the usage of your VM's disk partitions, I guess you output liking below :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 33 GiB, 38212254720 bytes, 68914560 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x49e5gv86

Device     Boot    Start   End   Sectors   Size Id  Type
/dev/sda1  *        487M    1G   1296880   537M  b  W95 FAT32 
/dev/sda2             1G   22G  46325760    21G  5  Extended
/dev/sda5             1G   22G  46325760    21G 83  Linux 
free space           22G   33G              11G
```

And I think your needed disk partition likes this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 33 GiB, 38212254720 bytes, 68914560 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x49e5gv86

Device     Boot    Start   End   Sectors   Size Id  Type
/dev/sda1  *        487M    1G   1296880   537M  b  W95 FAT32 
/dev/sda2             1G   22G  66325760    31G  5  Extended
/dev/sda5             1G   32G  66325760    31G 83  Linux 
free space           32G   33G               1G
```

Also, I do highly recommend you use partition tool `cfdisk` instead of APP `GParted` or partition tool parted.

Solution:

1.just log in your VM;

2.use `sudo cfdisk` to enter the permission of `cfdisk` on your VM's terminal;

Use `up` and `down` direction button to choose the partition, use `right` and `left` direction button to choose the operation, use `enter` button to make sure.

3.choose `Resize` button to expand the extended partition `Partition 2`, change default size into `31GB`, and push `enter`, and again type `yes`, and push `enter` to ok;

4.choose `Resize` button to enlarge the logical partition `Partition 5`, also, change default size into `31GB`, and push `enter`, and again type `yes`, and push `enter` to ok;

5.choose `Write` button to sync the new partition to the Disk, and use `Quit` button to quit `cfdisk`;

6.use `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5` on your VM's terminal to set all the file types of logical partition `Partition 5` into `ext4`;

7.Restart or reboot your virtual machine: sudo reboot.

Have fun!!!:)

OVER!